# How to add an userbar in a jade template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to understand how to set for exemple an userbar in my jade layout
actualy I have my layout.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body
    include userbar
    block content
```

In my include I only have the variable environment on my current page.

Don't bit me, I'll take an exemple in Symfony2 franmwork :D
for exemple if you have this code in your layout

```
{% render "AcmeBundle:Acme:menu" %}
```

It will call AcmeController and the menuAction() method regardless the current page

I would like to have the same system: the render in my jade page will call for exemple a requestHandler

```
exports.userbar = function(req, res){
    var user = 'ant';
    res.render('userbar', { user: user })
};
```

And now this will render my userbar :)
But I don't know how to do it with jade

If I am not clear ask me questions

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you have to add `{% render "AcmeBundle:Acme:menu" %}` this in each page too. In express, i think you do the same task much more easily. And you have different options here. First option is to use `user` middleware in specific request handlers like

Add an express middleware that simply finds user and set `app.locals` property. `app.locals` are visible for all jade files. For example, this simple middleware should be enough

```
var user = function(req, res, next)
{
   var user = db.find(...);
   app.locals({user: user});
   next(); // Do not render the page here, call the next() 
}
```

Then in your routing, use `var user` as follows :

```
app.get('/your_desired_url', user, function(req, res) {
    res.render('your_required_jade_file')
});
```

You can use this method in any request handler you want; for example,

```
app.get('/your_desired_url2', user, function(req, res) {
    res.render('your_required_jade_file')
});

app.get('/your_desired_url2', user, function(req, res) {
    res.render('your_required_jade_file')
});
```

In the second option, you can add this middleware as a general middleware, like

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var user = db.find(...);
    if(user) app.locals({user: user});
    else app.locals({user: null});

    next(); // Do not render the page here, call the next() 
});
```

In the second case, all of your requests are passed through this function, so in the .jade files, `user` varabile is always available.

In your .jade structure, you can use the followings

`layout.jade`

```
!!! 5
html
  head
  body
    include userbar
    block content
```

and for example `dashboard.jade`:

```
extends ./layout
block content
  // Your dashboard specific content goes here..
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Ok,but in this case I have to add user in each page I want to fetch my userbar

Comment: ok, i update the answer with more detail, if it solves your problem do not forget to set as correct.

Comment: No, I just add {% render "AcmeBundle:Acme:menu" %} one time in my layout and I would like to do the same in my jade layout

Comment: Right, the same thing can be done as in the answer, in jade and express.